# CompositeCollider2D плохо взаимодействует CapsulleCollider2D

Tags: unity3d

У меня на сцене есть тайлман и на нем висит композит коллайдер. Так же есть персонаж, на котором висит капсуль коллайдер и при приземлении на объекты тайлмапа у персонажа начинает незначительно меняться положение по x (настолько незначительно, что это можно понять только в инспекторе), и из-за этого ломаются анимации. Когда убираю композит коллайдер и оставляю только тайлмап коллайдер все становится нормально, за исключение того, что персонаж начинает запускать анимацию падения, когда проходит между элементами тайлмапа. Все работает как надо, когда помещаю персонажа не на объект тайлмапа. Пробовал поместить квадрат с капульным коллайдером, вся та же проблема. Скажите: композит коллайдер плохо работает с капсульным коллайдером или проблема на моей стороне?

Comment: На твоей стороне, анимация не должна так критично зависеть от погрешностей координат, которые являются нормой.

Comment: @Yaroslav Согласен, анимации починить не сложно. Меня беспокоит, а не повлечет ли это проблем в будущем. Просто у всех у кого я смотрел никакой погрешности не появлялось

Comment: А ты посмотри [видио](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U0U8Ddx4TgE) чуть более познавательных, чем гайды по юнити, которые в подавляющем большинстве трешкод и учти, что координата получается путём множества вычислений линейной алгебры и как я уже написал русским по белому: *являются нормой*. По мимо того, что абсолютная точность вообще не является целью физического движка, его цель в производительности. Плохому танцору... код не должен держаться на соплях!